# Creating a randomized circle from points in R/MatLab

Tags: python, r, matlab, random, topology

I'm doing some research with a professor at my university, and he is asking that I create some data for the purposes of Topological Data Analysis (TDA).

I used two packages from R and MatLab, however the authors seem to have a similar idea of how to randomize the data when performing an operation that relates to persistence of Betti points.

The issue in R (and MatLab) is that the circle is created with:

```
X <- circleUnif(n=30)
```

This generates a circle with evenly spaced points (30) with equal radius around a central point. To randomize the data, both examples from the author of the packages randomly sample from the data. This leads to an image that looks like this:
[Alpha Complex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dasfn.png)
What the professor asked is that I make it such that each point has some 'sigma' or deviation away from the radius. This would in essence create a 'fuzzy' ring with some degree of thickness. That way when persistence is performed on the data, the birth/death axes would have a more interesting output.

Around 2:30 in this video is an idea of what I'm trying to do:
[Persistent homology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_405791327&feature=iv&src_vid=h0bnG1Wavag&v=2PSqWBIrn90)

If someone has an idea how to do this in Python, I'm willing to try other languages as well.

Comment: So you want to add a uniformly distributed random value to the radius? Why is that difficult? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I got help from another person who has some R experience, and was able to create the random circle using some basic trigonometry. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Please never post ephemeral content like paste.ofcode.org on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work fine for you as long as you have numpy installed (using `pip install numpy` at the command line if you don't).

```
import numpy as np

def circleUnif(n=30, radius=1, sigma=0, center=(0, 0)):
    radii = np.random.randn(n) * sigma + radius
    angles = np.random.rand(n) * np.pi * 2

    x = radii * np.cos(angles)
    y = radii * np.sin(angles)

    return np.transpose([x, y]) + center
```

As an example usage:

```
>>> X = circleUnif(3, 1, 0, (2, 3))
>>> print X
[[1.29321773 3.70743115]
 [2.72817308 3.68539329]
 [2.35728855 2.06600595]]
```

In my experience though, python does not have the same maturity as R for topological data analysis. There isn't anything wrong with using the data science tools available in python, and you could generate data with python for use in R if you would like. But this is one of the few instances where python is really lacking in quality, stable tooling for a data science task. I might make some eventually, or somebody else might, but you don't have many options for most TDA algorithms right now.

Comment: I figured out the solution through R, however I was interested in the potential with Python. I will likely try your idea in the future if I attempt a solution via Python instead.